# problems moving to API 31 in ionic cordova framework

Tags: html, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

the problem is the following: I have my project in ionic cordova with API 30 and everything works perfectly, the problem happens when I want to go to API 31, what happens is that when going to API 31 only It works on Android 11 and its previous versions, but not on versions 12, 13 and it cannot be installed on the versions already mentioned

I tried to update ionic and all its dependencies to the latest version, hoping that would solve the problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a specific error on some logging or something else to go off of?

I believe you have to switch from java-8 to at least java-11.
You also might have to update cordova-android, or at least read about the breaking changes in the update docs: https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2022/07/12/cordova-android-release-11.0.0.html